# How do I align input labels to vertically correspond?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a form and love the look of it as is, but I can't for the life of me figure out a nicer way to display it.

I look I am going for is where all the labels vertically align to each other. I have posted some code on CodePen: [Link](http://codepen.io/sparcut/pen/7b39d50cb7ab662ef8f5f2292ebd6612/)

But here is a quick rundown of what I have done:

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><label for="f-name">Given Name: </label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="f-name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="l-name">Family Name: </label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="l-name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="address">Address: </label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="address"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="city">City: </label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="city"></td>
</tr>
```

SASS

```
table
  margin: 0 auto
    td:first-child
      text-align: right
```

Would be great if anyone knows of a simpler way to achieve this effect.

Comment: You can use the line-height property to set the same line height between the inputs and labels which will cause them to vertically center align. That way you wont need to use tables. Also consider using <label> elements and semantically linking them to the inputs using the 'for' attribute.

Comment: @LDJ Woops, I do have labels in my main project, I'll update the post and CodePen. Cheers.

Comment: It's already vertically aligned. Can you be more specific ?

Comment: @Pugazh Sorry, the effect has been achieved on codepen, however, it's a bit hacky since I'm using a table what it's not intended to be use for. So I am wondering what the correct way of active this effect would be.

Comment: have a look at bootstrap or rather it's grid component. it can certainly achieve what you need but it's not really flexible. you have to provide sufficient space, but also you can control collapsing for different devices by setting column classes (http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#horizontal-form)

Answer (score 0):

Tables are the only element that will reliably give you horizontal alignment over multiple rows in this manner. As you correctly identified, though, tables should not be used for layout purposes. So you have to find another solution to align all elements. Two suitable solutions come to mind:

- float all elements to the right, give all of the input fields the same width
- display both elements inline, and give all labels the same width

I'll go with the second option, as I don't like floating elements too much, for the reason that they will look much more broken if displayed not the way you intend it to by whatever weird browser out there. Inline elements with a set width are relatively safe in comparison, because worst case, your elements will simply be underneath each other and a viewer will probably not even notice that it's not the intended layout.

```css
label, input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}
label {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="f-name">Given Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="f-name" />
</div>
<div>
  <label for="l-name">Family Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="l-name" />
</div>
<div>
  <label for="address">Address:</label>
  <input type="text" id="address" />
</div>
<div>
  <label for="city">City:</label>
  <input type="text" id="city" />
</div>
```

One possible problem with this is that you need to guesstimate the width of your labels and put those guesses into your CSS, so the float-based solution gets an honorable mention here (it handles better because the labels don't need a fixed width) - however in practice, it will often be easy to find a globally applicable maximum width, as labels should be concise as it is and rarely will be whole sentences.

---

There's also the possibility of solving this with flexbox properties. That has the advtange of absolutely automatic width distribution, however older browsers don't necessarily support it (for a reference, check out [this graph on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/flexbox)), so I would recommend the above method unless you absolutely need this kind of functionality.

```css
.flex-container {
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}
label,
input {
  display: block;
}
label {
  flex: 1;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  text-align: right;
}
input {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <label for="f-name">Given Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="f-name" />
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <label for="l-name">Family Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="l-name" />
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <label for="address">Address:</label>
  <input type="text" id="address" />
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <label for="city">City:</label>
  <input type="text" id="city" />
</div>
```

Comment: Dam, I tried the fix width method, but as you said, it's not very flexible. Then with floats I totally agree, they can cause a lot of problems. I'll have to have a think of what method I should go with.

Comment: @sparcut: I also added a flexbox variant, which may suit your taste more... and also added my concerns regarding that ;)

Comment: Cheer, I am using the fixed width labels at the moment, but I my love flex boxes, but completely over looked their usefulness here. It is an internal web app so should be fine to use flex boxes, thanks!

Comment: @sparcut: Glad I could help! Also, if this or any answer has solved your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself - though there is no obligation to do this

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without tables easily enough:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
fieldset {
  border: none;
}
.question {
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
}
.question label {
  text-align: right;
  width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="question">
    <label for="f-name">Given Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="f-name">
  </div>
  <div class="question">
    <label for="l-name">Family Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="l-name">
  </div>
  <div class="question">
    <label for="address">Address:</label>
    <input type="text" id="address">
  </div>
  <div class="question">
    <label for="city">City:</label>
    <input type="text" id="city">
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Much of the styling here is arbitrary. The key is the height of the question div and the label line-height matching so the labels align centrally

Comment: This uses floats to basically achieve the same as inline display in my example. Inline display should be used because it won't interfere with the document flow. While there's nothing particularily wrong with using float for layout purposes as of today, you should still use inline display if all you're using it for is to display elements inline.